# Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html, referenceerror

I am attempting to play 3 songs, one after another by using the `onEnded` attribute in HTML5. Here is my first attempt, but I'm getting an error.

**Error :** `Uncaught ReferenceError: src is not defined
nextSong marioKart.html:49
onended marioKart.html:58`

Below is my code:

```
<script>
function nextSong(){
    var song = document.getElementById("player");
    song.attr(src,"countdown.wav");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="position:relative">
<audio controls autoplay="true" onEnded="nextSong()" onplay="race()" >
     <source id="player" src="startMusic.wav" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Can someone help me in achieving this ?

Comment: you ought to use song.setAttribute("src", "countdown.wav");

Comment: Also `song` doesn't have an `attr` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with jQuery element but you are using with DOM object also enclose `src` in quotes if it is not variable.

*Using jQuery object*

```
$(song).attr('src',"countdown.wav");
```

*Using DOM object*

```
song.src = "countdown.wav";
```